# Symmetric square of an $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-representation

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Consider the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ with basis $\{e,f,h\}$ satisfying the standard commutation relations.

Let $V$ be an $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-representation over $\mathbb{C}$, that isn't necessarily simple. Then, the space $Sym^2(V)$ has a natural $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-action. Now, pick some $v\in V$ and consider $v^2\in Sym^2(V)$. Suppose $v^2 = e.w$ for some $w\in Sym^2(V)$. Then, I want to claim that $v$ must lie in the subspace of $V$ spanned by the eigenvectors of $h$ in $V$ having strictly positive eigenvalues.

I can prove this by fixing a basis for $V$ for which the $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ action is nice, but the proof eventually gets quite messy. So, I am looking for a nicer proof, that hopefully doesn't require fixing any coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of working with $Sym^2(V)$, we will work with $V\otimes V$, for notational convenience. As $V\otimes V$ contains $Sym^2(V)$ as a proper subrepresentation, if $v^2=e\cdot w$ for some $w\in Sym^2(V)$, we must have that $v\otimes v=e\cdot \tilde w$ for some $\tilde w\in V\otimes V$.

Let $V=\oplus_i V_i$ be the decomposition of $V$ into a direct sum of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-representations. Then, we get a corresponding decomposition $v=\sum_i v_i$ such that $v_i\in V_i$ for all $i$. Then, as $v\otimes v=e\cdot w$, it is clear that there exist $w_i\in V_i\otimes V_i$ such that $v_i\otimes v_i=e\cdot w_i$. Therefore, without loss of generality, we can assume that $V$ is irreducible.

Suppose $\dim(V)=n+1$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. Then, there exists an $h$-eigenbasis $\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ of $V$ such that the $e$ and $f$ actions are given by:

$$e\cdot x_i=x_{i+1}, f\cdot x_j=x_{j-1},$$
for all $0\leq i\leq n-1$ and $1\leq j\leq n$.

Write $v=\sum_i c_ix_i$ for $c_i\in \mathbb{C}$. Then, we have $v\otimes v=\sum_{i,j}c_ic_jx_i\otimes x_j$.  Pick the smallest $i$ such that $c_i\neq 0$. Then, $c_i^2x_i\otimes x_i$ is the summand in $v\otimes v$ having strictly the smallest eigenvalue for the $h$-action. Therefore, as we have that $v\otimes v=e\cdot w$ for some $w\in V\otimes V$, there must exist $w'\in V\otimes V$ such that $x_i\otimes x_i = e\cdot w'$. Hence, without loss of generality, we can assume that $v=x_k$ for some $k$.

So, given that $x_k\otimes x_k=e\cdot w$ for some $w\in V\otimes V$, we want to show that $h$ acts on $x_k$ with a positive eigenvalue. For the sake of a contradiction, suppose $h$ acts on $x_k$ with a non-positive eigenvalue. Therefore, we must have that $h$ actis on $x_k\otimes x_k$ with a non-positive eigenvalue. As $x_k\otimes x_k=e\cdot w$, we must have that $h$ acts on $w$ with a strictly negative eigenvalue. Let $V'\subseteq V$ be the subspace spanned by $\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}\}$ (that is, all but the highest weight vector). Then, we must have that $w\in V'\otimes V'\subseteq V\otimes V$.

Define the linear function:
$$\phi:V\otimes V\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$$
$$x_i\otimes x_j\mapsto (-1)^i.$$

Then, we claim that $\phi(e\cdot x)=0$ for all $x\in V'\otimes V'$. To see this, we note that $V'\otimes V'$ is spanned by vectors for the form $x_i\otimes x_j$ for $0\leq i,j\leq n-1$. Hence, for such $i,j$, we have:
$$e\cdot(x_i\otimes x_j)=x_{i+1}\otimes x_j+x_i\otimes x_{j+i},$$
which makes it clear that $\phi(e\cdot(x_i\otimes x_j))=0$.

In particular, as $x_k\otimes x_k = e\cdot w'$, we must have $f(x_k\otimes x_k)=0$. This contradicts the fact that $f(x_k\otimes x_k)=(-1)^k$, which follows from the definition of $f$. This contradiction completes the proof.